# Paginating result set in oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, pagination

I have high transactional service with oracle db as backend.Many number of clients will be calling our service to get the data.When we receive the request for data, we need to query the db, get the result set and send them in the paginated way.I dont want the query.But wanted to know what really happens.say if the result set has 20,000 rows, and if we need to send 100 data per page in repsonse,how can i mention that there is remaining set of data, in the response,so that the client needs to hit our service to get the next next pages?.Say the response is in json format.How should the resposne format look like?.I'm new to oracle.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To select the data the paginated way, try

```
    select order_id, order_descr
  from (select order_id, order_descr, row_number() over(order by order_date desc) r
          from orders
          where customer_id = 123)
 where r between 1 and 101
```

to display order 1 upto 100 (first page) of customer_id 123.

If you receive at client side more than 100 rows of data then more data exists.

The inner select statement with order by clause is necessary.